# Accessing a hidden TD in Data Tables in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datatables

I have a row in a table where the ID column is hidden by Data Tables. This means it is not displayed in the actual HTML, but rather just in the Data Tables JS.

I wrote some JS to try and extract the data, but again, it's not in the HTML for it's been useless.

I've looked online and found functions such as

> fnGetPosition() - http://datatables.net/api#fnGetPosition
>
> fnGetData() - http://datatables.net/api#fnGetData

However, I don't actually use dataTables directly through javascript, I set everything up through ASP.NET MVC 3 and would like to not have to import all the Data Tables stuff into my JS.

I've thought about just adding a `display:none` class to each of those TDs and the Th but that just seems messy.

Does anyone know of any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTML5 data attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).  You can access it using jQuery in a variety of ways.

```
<table>
    <tr data-key1="val1" data-key2="val2">
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery option 1:

```
$(tr).data('key1');
$(tr).data('key2', 'value2');
```

jQuery option 2:

```
$(tr).attr('data-key1');
```

Comment: Do you know how custom data attributes are supported through the C# DataTables implementation?

Comment: I do not ... if I am using MVC, I usually create my HTML tables myself, and add the `data` attribute for any data I need that's not being viewed.